# why React navigation locked me in a one screen?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

this code don't allow me to navigate to another screens in the app . when token become true  `this.props.navigation.navigate('Map');` lock me inside map screen only

```
    state = {token: null};

async componentWillMount() {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fb_token');

    if (token) {
        this.setState({ token });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Map');

    } else {
        this.setState({ token: false });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any question in this post. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. 

setParams takes an object as parameter.

Comment: i corrected the code sorry about that